# PHP Username and Password verification

Tags: php, sql, database, passwords

I'm currently working on a class project where I have to verify the username and password against a database. I stored the values of the username and password in individual arrays and I'm trying to verify that the user input matches one of the values in there. However, that's not happening, and I'm not sure how to fix it. Thanks for your help!

```
<? 
connectDB();
$sql = "SELECT* FROM employee";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die ("SQL error: " . mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$password = array();
$username = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $password[] = $row['emp_pword'];
    $username[] = $row['emp_username'];
}
var_dump($password);
var_dump($username);
?>  

    <?php if (isset($_REQUEST['page1_submit'])) {
        if (($_REQUEST['pword'] == $password) and ($_REQUEST['user'] == $username)) { 
        header('location:home_agent.php');
        } else { ?>
    <h2>Wrong Password! Try again.</h2>
                    <form method="POST" action="login.php"> 
                         <table class="info">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Username:</th>
                                <td><input type="text" NAME="username" />
                                </td>
                                <th>Password:</th>
                                <td><input type="password" NAME="pword" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="page2_submit" value="SUBMIT" />
                    <input class="submit" type="reset" value="RESET" />
                    </form>
    <?php }
```

Comment: You're doing your query wrongly. Add a `WHERE` to your query, and look for records that match the username and password you're getting from the user. That way you get just a single row (or none at all, if the details don't match.) And look up how to use prepared statements, too.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Do you know why I'm getting this error though:  Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\wamp\www\Project\login.php on line 24

Comment: You have a typo in your code - `$_REQUEST['user']` should be `$_REQUEST['username']`.

Answer (score -1):

ME TOO THINKS YOU ARE WRONG . 
YOU JUST EXECUTE QUERY 
" SELECT * FROM TBLE_NAME WHERE username=$username AND password=$password"

check this query gives a non empty list for verify login

thats all.